# Check file exists and find a string error in batch

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a batch file to find files. If file exits, then find the `Request time` words inside of these file. If `Request time` word found, I want to output `FileName, "O"` as csv file. If words not found, output `FileName, "X"` to csv file. Here is my batch script.

```
@echo off
Set "filePath=%~dp0"
:: Please change the filePath with your filePath.

if exist %filePath%nodes.txt goto Label1
echo.
echo Cannot find  %filePath%nodes.txt
echo.
Pause
goto :eof

:Label1
for /f %%i in (%filePath%nodes.txt) do call :check %%i
Pause
goto :eof

:check
Set "fOut=%filePath%pingRsl.csv"

if EXIST "%filePath%%1.txt" (
find "Request time" %filePath%%1.txt>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (echo %1, O>>"%fOut%") else (echo %1, X>>"%fOut%")
) ELSE (
echo %1,"">>"%fOut%"
) 
goto :eof
```

But, the result is not as I expected. I can't figure it out what its wrong.

Comment: What is the error you get? Try turing `@echo on` at the start instead of off and tell us the last line that is executed or if there is an error what it is and at which line

Comment: @Monacraft Now, I can solve it myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I can solve the problem.

```
@echo off
Set "filePath=%~dp0"
:: Please change the filePath with your filePath.

if exist %filePath%nodes.txt goto Label1
echo.
echo Cannot find  %filePath%nodes.txt
echo.
Pause
goto :eof

:Label1
for /f %%i in (%filePath%nodes.txt) do call :check %%i
Pause
goto :eof

:check
Set "fOut=%filePath%pingRsl.csv"
if EXIST "%filePath%%1.txt" (
>nul find "Request time" "%filePath%%1.txt" && (
  echo %1,"X">>"%fOut%"
) || (
  echo %1,"O">>"%fOut%"
)
) ELSE (
echo %1,"">>"%fOut%"
) 
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a few changes, *(from :Label1 onwards)*, I hope they help you.

```bat
:Label1
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%filePath%nodes.txt") Do Call :check "%%~A"
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:check
Set "fOut=%filePath%pingRsl.csv"

If Not Exist "%filePath%%1.txt" GoTo :EOF
(Find /I "Request time" < "%filePath%%1.txt" > Nul && (
      Echo %~1, O) || Echo %~1, X)>>"%fOut%"
GoTo :EOF
```

Also remember that whilst you've temporarily `Set "filePath=%~dp0"` that it includes a trailing back slash. You therefore need to ensure that your end user when they `:: Please change the filePath with your filePath.` that they also include a trailing back slash otherwise you'll need to adjust all instances of `%filePath%` with `%filePath%\`.

Comment: This site already has a system in place for showing your appreciation. _Marking my answer as accepted is thanks enough_.

Answer (score 1):

Standard `delayed expansion` trap. Use the `search` facility in the top bar to find `delayed expansion` for an expose.

Summary: Any `%var%` in a code block (parenthesised sequence of commands) is replaced by the value of that variable *before* the block is executed.

So

```
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (echo %1, O>>"%fOut%") else (echo %1, X>>"%fOut%")
```

should be

```
if errorlevel 1 (echo %1, O>>"%fOut%") else (echo %1, X>>"%fOut%")
```

This is the original meaning of `if errorlevel` and means if the *run-time* errorlevel is 1 *or greater than 1*